# String not accessible in same class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, variables, permissions

I have code to show a toast:

```
public void checkchallenge(View v) {
        String algo = null;
        if(algo == "123")
        {

Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "You have " + messages ;
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
...
```

the error in eclipse that I am getting is:

> messages cannot be resolved to a variable

The variable "messages" is being called in some code above it:

```
String messages = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGES);
final TextView messages1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.envelope);
```

Maybe it's because I don't know Java too well but why isn't my string variable "messages" or "messages1" getting recognized in my code?  I have a feeling it has to do with permissions of the code but when I remove the "final" part off of the messages 1 TextView I get the same error.

Confused!

```
Here is the entire code to the class:

public class Homepage extends Activity {






    //URL to get JSON Arrays
   public static String url = "http://10.0.2.2/android/SQL.php?username='";
   public static String usernamefromlogin;
   public static TextView errorchecking; 

    //JSON Node Names 
    private static final String TAG_USER = "users";
    private static final String TAG_WINS = "wins";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGES = "messages";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "fullname";
    private static final String TAG_DISPLAY = "displayname";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_PW = "password";
    private static final String TAG_CREATED = "created_at";
    private static final String TAG_UPDATED = "updated_at";


    JSONArray user = null;

    //disable back button
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reshomepage);


        //Get login name from EditText in login screen and concatenate it to PHP user-name for _GET command in 3 steps.
        //Step 1: Get intent from previous activity
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        getIntent().getExtras();




        //Step 2: convert intent (intent) to string called "usernamefromlogin"     //error checking in log cat to see value of "usernamefromlogin"      
       usernamefromlogin = intent.getExtras().getString("username2");      Log.d("log of usernamefromlogin", usernamefromlogin);

        //Step 3: take the string "url" and add string "usernamefromlogin" after it
       String url5 = url.concat(usernamefromlogin);
       String url6 = url5.concat("'");
        //find TextView "errorchecking" and send the string "url6" to it so it can display in log cat
       Log.d("log of URL6 in it's final state", url6);







        // Creating new JSON Parser
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL from the final string "url6"
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url6);
        //Logcat check value for TAG_USER



        try {
            // Getting JSON Array

            user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
            JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);






            // Storing  JSON item in a String Variable

            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String messages = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGES);
            String wins = c.getString(TAG_WINS);
            String display = c.getString(TAG_DISPLAY);
            String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
            String pw = c.getString(TAG_PW);
            String created = c.getString(TAG_CREATED);
            String updated = c.getString(TAG_UPDATED);



            //Importing TextView

            final TextView name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvfullname);
             TextView messages1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.envelope);
            final TextView wins1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wins);
            final TextView created1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvcreated_at);
            final TextView updated1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvupdated_at);




            //Set JSON Data in its respectable TextView

      name1.setText("Hello " + name);





      updated1.setText("Your last login was " + updated);






 // print error if applicable.
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

    public void checkchallenge(View v) {
        String algo = null;
        if(algo == "123")
        {


              // display pop up message (toast)
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "You have " + messages1 ;
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();


        }else
        {
        // display pop up message (toast)
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "You have no new Challenges";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: _The variable "messages" is being called in some code above it:_ There is such a thing as **variable scope**. You can only use a variable of it is visible in your current scope.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your comment.  So if the variable is used once, I can't use it again?

I am used to programming in PHP where a variable can be used indefinitely on the same script so this is very confusing to me.

Comment: It can be due to many reasons. `..called in some code above it` is not that clear. Please show the structure of the code where you are doing this. We might be able to help better.

Comment: I just updated with the entire code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your messages variable is defined inside other method it won't be seen at the point you showed.

Comment: I just updated my question with my entire code.

Do you think it's because I have the string inside of a try/catch statement?

Comment: It sure is, all that variables are scoped inside the try/catch, outside that they doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I guess my new question is, how do I remove the try and catch without breaking my code?

I tried removing them and then everything went haywire, I keep getting "Unhandled exception type JSONException" for all the strings now

Comment: @user I don't think this strategy for learning java is going to work. Don't just stop every time you have a problem and ask for the solution. Go through some tutorials and use google. Try to understand the error, Java is extremely well documented.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I agree in part with you. Although I think the same for my personal study there are different ways in which people learn :) and programming is a lot like a apprentiship based discipline, is great to grasp insight from the way other people think about the problems :)

Comment: @prmottajr There aren't many different ways to think about `Unhandled exception type X` and `X cannot be resolved to a variable`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis you are right on that :) I was talking (writing?) about the strategy of stoping and asking for help. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the code is making the `String` messages and `TextView` local variables inside a method.  If you want to access these objects within the entire class they should be declared as fields.

```
public SomeClass{
    String messages;
    final TextView messages1;

    public void checkchallenge(View v) {
        //Method implementation
    }

    public void someOtherMethod(){
        this.messages = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGES);
        this.messages1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.envelope);
    }
}
```